# Proving by contraposition that, for any rational number $n$, if $n^5-6n^4+27<0$, then $n\leq10$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove that, for any rational number $n$, if $n^5-6n^4+27<0$, then $n\leq10$.
>
> This needs to be done as a proof by contrapositive

We will do a proof by contrapositive.

Prove that for any rational number $n$, if $n>10$, then $n^{5}-6n^{4}+27\geq0$.

I started by stating the above, and then simplifying the equation down to $n^{4}(n-6)+27$

Comment: Here's the first few words... "*Suppose that $n>10$.  Then...*"

Comment: Note... $n^5 = n\times n^4$ and so $n^5-6n^4 = \dots$ which if we were to have supposed that would mean...

Comment: Do you know what the contrapositive of an if-then statement is? Can you write down the contrapositive of the given if-then statement? Only after writing down the statement to be proved can we begin to try to prove it.

Comment: I've updated the problem with where I've gotten so far

Comment: $n>6 \implies n^5 > 6n^4 > 6n^4 - 27$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n>10$ be rational.

Then $n-6 > 4 > 0$.

Furthermore, since $n>10>0$, then $n^4 > 0$.

Since $(n-6)>0$ and $n^4>0$, we have their product $n^4(n-6)>0\geq -27$. This ultimately implies $n^4(n-6) + 27 \geq 0$, so we conclude that $n^5 - 6n^4 + 27 \geq 0$.

Then apply the contrapositive to get your QED.